# CMake add library libpq (postgreSQL) mac c++ clion

Tags: c++, postgresql, cmake, clion

I'm surprised there is no official c++ library for postgres catching up with the standard. So I have to use the original c lipq. But how do I tell the linker to include it with CMake? I expect it to be a one short line in CMake.

All I see is find_package (what even a package is?, is's mentioned in the quick JetBrains' CMake tutorial, but not in the official), target_link_libraries, find_library.

All I'm asking for is like in Python (crossplatform) `pip install my_library` and then `import my_library`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In CMake, a package is an external library (or tool) that can be located using scripts (either bundled with CMake, or written by someone else).

`find_package` command runs that script. When a package is found, the script sets a number of variables pointing to include directories, libraries to link, etc.

A script for Postgres is included with CMake, so it should be possible to do something like this:

```
# This command attempts to find the library, REQUIRED argument is optional
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)

# Add include directories to your target. PRIVATE is useful with multi-target projects - see documentation of target_include_directories for more info
target_include_directories(MyTarget PRIVATE ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Add libraries to link your target againts. Again, PRIVATE is important for multi-target projects
target_link_libraries(MyTarget PRIVATE ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES})
```

That's a simple example of how `find_package` can be used. Variables with `PostgreSQL_` prefix are set by the script run by `find_package` command and are described in here: [FindPostgreSQL documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindPostgreSQL.html)

As a side note, `find_library` can be used too, although it is "lower level". The command searches for a static/shared library, and is used to implement scripts used by `find_package`. As long as a library you are trying to use has a `find_package` script, it shouldn't be necessary to use `find_library`.

**UPDATE (CMake 3.14 and newer)**

Starting with CMake 3.14, it is possible to use so called "imported target" for Postgres, which is a bit simpler and in line with [modern CMake](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1#use-exported-targets-of-external-packages):

```
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)

# This line adds both include paths and libraries for Postgres
target_link_libraries(MyTarget PRIVATE PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL)
```

`PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL` is imported target created by the `Find` module. This target has include directories and libraries set as its `INTERFACE` properties. This means that in the example above `MyTarget` will "inherit" include directories and libraries from `PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL`, without having to set them explicitly.